# Creating a mixed pixel/percentage layout with divs

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to make a page layout as can be seen in the attached picture. The problem is that I can't get it working properly. I spent half a day trying to get it working, but without success. I just want a fixed width div for the menu and next to that two divs creating columns that each take half of the remaining page width. Heights all need to be content dependent.

Anybody an idea? I could find much info about such mixed perecentage/pixel layouts, but I can't imagine it's that hard.

Picture: [image]

Comment: Negative margins will solve your problems. All of them.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
<style type="text/css">
.container
{
  padding-left: 160px;
  position: relative;
}
.leftmenu
{
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red; /* For demo purposes */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.width50
{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.left-content
{
  height: 300px;
  background: green /* For demo purposes */
}
.right-content
{
  height: 150px;
  background: blue   /* For demo purposes */
}
.clear
{
  clear: both;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftmenu"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="width50 left-content"></div>
    <div class="width50 right-content"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is only the inside container (without header or footer)

Comment: That works perfectly. Here I created a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/R6LCz/) with your code. We can see the result by re-sizing the result panel. +1

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have the time to take a look at it until now. It works like a charm in all browsers except IE. The problem is that it is for a company that only works with IE. How to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Any help with this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386171/how-to-ensure-the-background-image-inside-a-div-is-evenly-shown/26386885?noredirect=1#comment41429026_26386885

Answer (score 0):

A javascript approach.

Here I had created the layout exactly you need. [Check this link](http://mockupwebsite.com/testing/test-layout.html).

Re-size the browser and refresh it. You can see that working!

I used the following script to find the screen resolution and then calculating the content width.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
wscreen = window.innerWidth; //Determine screen resolution
content_width = (wscreen - 160); //Adjusting the screen
document.getElementById("container").style.width = content_width + "px"; // Adding the width to CSS
</script>
```

Pure CSS approach will also works.

Cheers !!!